# Cross Browser / Mozilla issue

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am making my CV in a website here is the link http://anaxshipping.com/georgepkcv/studies.html

If you open it with latest Chrome the first section "Studies" with the 2 images Athens,Vilnius it appears as it suppose to be.

If you open it with latest Mozilla that section appears at the top of the page and "very right". Do you see it? If you disable the overflow:hidden it will fix it for Mozilla but it will cause problems to Chrome.

Do you have any ideas about that?
I am using the latests versions of both Chrome and Mozilla.

One final question for this kind of websites (CV) what copyrights should anyone write at the bottom of the page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try to use display property at .ggrid class from your custom.css.
I tried:

```
display:inline;
```

or

```
display: inline-block;
```

That worked for me for all browsers.

2) For your last question i would suggest something like that:

```
Copyright 2014 <Your Name>. All Rights Reserved.
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it would be just one line of css.

I don't know if I am getting out of this topic , but any comments about the general styling , or some ideas that you be nice to implement I would appreciate it!

Thanks for the answer again!